# Why ContextMenu Command and CommandParameter are not working in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGird`, then it's include `Expander` and `ContextMenu`.

This `DataGird` is grouping. And, it's has different `ContextMenu` between `Expander` and `DataGridItem`.

However, I want to binding `MenuItem` `Command` to my command, and pass `DataGird`'s `SelectedItems` or `SelectedIndex` to `Command`.

But this command is not invoked. Even if it work, the parameter is not pass when I survey some method got goal (like set property `tag`).

So, I want to know what's correct method.

**General**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel x:Name="VM"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              SelectionMode="Extended"
              RowHeaderWidth="0"
              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <!-- Remove the focus indication for the selected cell -->
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="No." Binding="{Binding No}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="False"  MouseRightButtonDown="Expander_MouseRightButtonDown" ButtonBase.Click="Expander_Click">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                                    <ContextMenu>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="Insert" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I" Command="{Binding InsertGroupItems"/>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="Remove" InputGestureText="Ctrl+D" Command="{Binding RemoveGroupItems"/>
                                                    </ContextMenu>
                                                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text=" item(s)"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter>
                                            <ItemsPresenter.ContextMenu>
                                                <ContextMenu>
                                                    <ContextMenu>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="Insert" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I" Command="{Binding InsertSelectedItems" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="Remove" InputGestureText="Ctrl+D" Command="{Binding RemoveSelectedItems" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                                                    </ContextMenu>
                                            </ItemsPresenter.ContextMenu>
                                        </ItemsPresenter>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**This work to invoke command, but can't pass parameter**

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Insert" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.InsertSelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Remove" InputGestureText="Ctrl+D" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.RemoveSelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="False"  MouseRightButtonDown="Expander_MouseRightButtonDown" ButtonBase.Click="Expander_Click">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                                        <ContextMenu>
                                                            <MenuItem Header="Insert" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I" Command="{Binding InsertGroupItems}"/>
                                                            <MenuItem Header="Remove" InputGestureText="Ctrl+D" Command="{Binding RemoveGroupItems}"/>
                                                        </ContextMenu>
                                                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text=" item(s)"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

*BTW, how to cast `SelectedItems` when got parameter?*

**It's not work**

```
private void Excute(object parameter)
{
    IList list = parameter as IList;
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Remove((Data)item);
    }
}
```

So, maybe I have three problems.

1. The `ContextMenu` not working.
2. The `CommandParameter` not passing.
3. How to convert `SelectedItems` to a list?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `MenuItem` in a `ContextMenu` can't use an `ElementName` to bind to the `DataGrid` because the `ContextMenu` and the `DataGrid` belong to different element trees.

What you could do is to bind the `Tag` property of the `ItemsPresenter` to the `DataGrid` and then bind to properties of the `DataGrid` through the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<ItemsPresenter Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
    <ItemsPresenter.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Insert2" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I"
                        DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.InsertSelectedItems}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedIndex}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove2" InputGestureText="Ctrl+D"
                        DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveSelectedItems}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ItemsPresenter.ContextMenu>
</ItemsPresenter>
```

> How to convert SelectedItems to a list?

Like you are doing. This should work provided that the binding to the `SelectedItems` property of the `DataGrid` works:

```
private void Execute(object parameter)
{
    IList list = parameter as IList;
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Remove((Data)item);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Of course you cannot use `ElementName` when binding to the `CommandArgument` either. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Insert" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I"
                          Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.InsertSelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.SelectedIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Remove" InputGestureText="Ctrl+D"
                          Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.RemoveSelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. I try your code is not work, If I define `Tag` and `ContextMenu` by style in `<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>`. This is confused. I will update my code.

Comment: It surely works for me. I don't know what "this is confused" means.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Maybe you should read my answer once more.

Comment: Of course you cannot use ElementName when binding to the CommandArgument either.

Comment: Oh.. Maybe you can see my update code. I will try again use a empty project.

Comment: Please see my edited answer that is based on your edit.

Comment: You are right. I try your answer, then it's work! but edited answer can't work.

Comment: What do you mean? It works but it doesn't work...? What does "can't work" mean? What happens?

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't it? You should try it out. It binds to the DataGrid itself.

Comment: It's OK. Thanks a lot.